# React, open all expanders when particular redux action is called

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-observable

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to open all expanders when someone starts submission. It sounds pretty easy but solution I came about is pretty ugly. When action is dispatched it changes the state in redux to signal component that it has to open expanders, then immediately after that calls another action to reset reducer state. I'm using redux observable so I can also call start and end in my epics just to signal component. However this approach seems quite strange, is there a better way to signal the component to do some action? This is my pseudo code below:

```
class ExpanderWrapper : React.Component<any,any>
{
    state = {expanded:false}

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)
    {
        if(newProps.forceExpand) {
         this.setState({expanded:true});
          this.props.forceExpandEnded();
        }
    }


     render() {
       return( <Expander expanded={this.state.expanded} 
                onExpandChange={()=>this.setState({expanded:false)} />
     }
}


connect(ExpandWrapper,... map forceExpand and forceExpandEnded() here)


reducer(state,action)
{
  if(action === forceExpandStarted)
   return {...state,forceExpand:true}
  if(action === forceExpandEnded)
   return {...state,forceExpand:false}
}
```

Comment: You wrote C++ in your former life huh? =D

Comment: Just university : ) Because of "pseudo code" ?

Comment: The `class Derived : Base` syntax and curly braces on newlines 

Comment: I've got .NET background. I haven't noticed that ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question here is how to have components observe application-specific events/signals when additional state doesn't seem necessary.

Your solution involves adding the `forceExpand` signal to the application state, which might be where the ugliness resides. You are forced to hook into the state tree to get that signal, and then reset it for each `<Expander>` that is currently rendered.

An alternative could be to utilize RxJS without redux-observable. With this solution, you create a `Subject` that emits whenever a relevant action is pushed to the redux store. Then, you subscribe to and unsubscribe from this `Observable` in your Component.

A quick and dirty example:

```
// in some module
export const ExpandSignal = new Rx.Subject();
export const ExpandSignalActionTypes = [ ... ];

// middleware that looks at the redux actions
const signalMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if (ExpandSignalActionTypes.includes(action.type))
    ExpandSignal.next();

  return next(action);
};

// implement with wrapper, or integrate into existing component
class ExpandWrapper extends React.Component {
  state = { expanded: false };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.subscription = ExpandSignal.subscribe(() => this.setState({ expanded: true });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Expander expanded={this.state.expanded}
                onExpandedChanged={() => this.setState({ expanded: false })} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I like it, it's much more clean. How does that fit redux principles? Isn't it bypassing redux rules?

Comment: Assuming your `<Expander>` state is separate from your redux state (each `<Expander>` manages its own internal state), I would say it doesn't break redux rules.

Comment: Thanks! The only reason I connected it to redux is just this notification.